# Adding XAML style to a datagrid with an ItemSource binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am binding my datagrid to an observable collection in the c# code behind with DataGrid.ItemSource = mileageRecords.

When I try to style the XAML of the datagrid using  I get an error stating. 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll... Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Any thoughts.

Here is the XAML

```
        <DataGrid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </DataGrid.Effect>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="RowHeaderToggleButton"
            Click="ToggleButton_Click"
            Cursor="Hand" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>


        <Style x:Name="RowDetailTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="DarkRed"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template"></Setter>
```

Comment: posted part of the xaml that is failing

Comment: The error is not occurring in the code that you have posted. Please post the XAML code for your DataGrid. I think you may have put invalid code within your <DataGrid></DataGrid> code.